# Getting array with same key from all objects separate into one object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new with using underscore npm module,I have Array like below.

```
var array=[ { app_name: 'agregador',
                   string_ok: 'ca.',
                   string_cancel: 'Cancelar',
                 },
                 { app_name: 'CANDA',
                   string_ok: 'ta.',
                   string_cancel: 'pqr',
                 },
                 { app_name: 'Belgium',
                   string_ok: 'nl',
                   string_cancel: 'test',
                 } ]

I want output array like this

        var output=[ {  app_name: 'agregador',
                        app_name: 'CANDA',
                        app_name: 'Belgium'
                     },
                     {  string_ok: 'ca.',
                        string_ok: 'ta.',
                        string_ok: 'nl'
                     },
                     {  string_cancel: 'Cancelar',
                        string_cancel: 'pqr',
                        string_cancel: 'test',
                      } ]
```

Which underscore function will be applicable for this?

Comment: the output is invalid. keys of an object need to be unique. But you could have an array of the keys

Comment: you can't create duplicate keys in object